# how to contraint that jsonb column must be a json/object?

Tags: postgresql, json, jsonb

I have a column that have json datatype

how to make a constraint or validation in my postgresql to validate that this jsonb column value must be a hash/object/json

because apparently after some testing besides hash/json/object jsonb accept array and string too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following `CHECK` constraint

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT OnlyJsonObject
  CHECK (jsonb_typeof(YourColumn) = 'object');
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/52gLhcL2)

See also [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.11.2.2.24.1.1.1).

Comment: just want to make sure 'object' in here means json object right? just check it yeah 'object' means json object

Comment: See fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/52gLhcL2

Comment: so apparently my postgresql autocasting the check constraint into this `((jsonb_typeof(roles) = 'object'::text))` I have past the same expression to your dbfiddle and it still works fine, any commentary on that?

Comment: It's normalizing the constraint so that the implicit conversion from `varchar` to `text` is explicit